# Problema manejando un Array con importes

Tags: javascript

estoy realizando varios ejercicios y uno de ellos me indica lo siguiente:

Haz una función que reciba un array con importes que devuelva el resultado final de la suma de los importes de todos los meses que tienen ganancia, a excepción de los que superen un importe de $ 1.000.
Pero me devuelve el siguiente error:
"La función sumatoriaBajoImporte ejecutada con los meses [300, 0, -250, -100, 0, 400, 600, 1200, 5000, 0, 1000, 1000] debería darnos como resultado 3300"

A continuacion, el codigo:

```
function sumatoriaBajoImporte ([unPeriodo]) {
let sumatoria = 0;
for (i=0; i < unPeriodo; i++) {
    let mes = unPeriodo[i];
    if ( mes <=1000 && mes > 0) {
        sumatoria = sumatoria + mes
    }
    return sumatoria;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Tienes varios errores en el código:

1. El parámetro recibido por la función no debe estar entre corchetes `[unPeriodo]`, simplemente el nombre de la variable `unPeriodo`
2. La segunda expresión del ciclo `for` especifica el final y debe ser la cantidad de elementos en el arreglo `i < unPeriodo.length`, te faltó agregar `.length`
3. Estás devolviendo el resultado dentro del ciclo y debe ser fuera.

```js
// El parámetro no debe estar entre corchetes
function sumatoriaBajoImporte(unPeriodo) {
    let sumatoria = 0;
    // El fin del ciclo se determina por la cantidad de elementos en el arreglo
    for (i = 0; i < unPeriodo.length; i++) {
        let mes = unPeriodo[i];
        if ( mes <=1000 && mes > 0) {
            sumatoria += mes;
        }
    }
    // El total debe devolverse fuera del ciclo
    return sumatoria;
}

// Resultado: 3300
console.log(sumatoriaBajoImporte([300, 0, -250, -100, 0, 400, 600, 1200, 5000, 0, 1000, 1000]));
```

Answer (score 3):

La respuesta de Triby esta perfecta, pero yo agregaría que si quieres hacer el proceso en una simple linea podrías usar filter y reduce. Aquí de te muestro un ejemplo de como seria:

```
    const importe = [300, 0, -250, -100, 0, 400, 600, 1200, 5000, 0, 1000, 1000];
    const sumatoriaBajoImporte = unPeriodo => unPeriodo.filter( mes => mes<1001 && mes >-1 ).reduce( (acumulador,mes) => acumulador + mes );
    console.log(sumatoriaBajoImporte(importe))
```

Básicamente, filtramos el array con el criterio de que ningún importe debe ser mayor a 1000 ni menor a 0 y después sumamos todos sus elementos.
Posiblemente estés iniciando en la programación por lo que no hay prisa si no entiendes el concepto de las funciones lambda, pero igual tómalo en cuenta para un futuro.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: Interesante respuesta, pero creo que se puede dejar solo `.reduce()`, sin `.filter()`, usando asignación ternaria: `const sumatoriaBajoImporte = unPeriodo => unPeriodo.reduce( (acumulador,mes) => acumulador += (mes <= 1000 && mes >= 0) ? mes : 0);` ... de todos modos... +1